# Elasticsearch Completion - Return top 10 docs by score

Tags: java, autocomplete, elasticsearch, autosuggest

I'm using Elasticsearch and the completion type for an autocomplete.
For an empty search I would like to return the top ten documents across the whole mapping (by score).

My mapping is created as such:

```
String type = AutoCompleteServiceImpl.AC_TYPE;

XContentBuilder mapping = jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
          .startObject(type)
            .startObject("properties")
              .startObject(AutoCompleteServiceImpl.AC_FIELD)
                .field("type", "completion")
              .endObject()
            .endObject()
          .endObject()
        .endObject();

PutMappingResponse mappingResponse = 
  client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(index)
  .setType(type).setSource(mapping)
  .execute().actionGet();
```

Where AC_FIELD = "keyword_suggest".

I add documents via:

```
XContentBuilder json =  jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
          .startObject(AC_FIELD)
            .array("input", record.getInput().toArray(new String[1]))
            .field("output", record.getOutput())
            .field("weight", record.getWeight())
          .endObject()
        .endObject();

elasticsearch.getClient()
    .prepareIndex(elasticsearch.getIndexName(), AC_TYPE, record.getId())
    .setSource(json)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

When the user enters text (searchTermLC) I use a **suggest** call, rather than a search ([Completion Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)). I call this:

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder suggestionsBuilder = new CompletionSuggestionBuilder(AC_TYPE);
suggestionsBuilder.field(AC_FIELD);
suggestionsBuilder.text(searchTermLC);
if (limit != null)
  suggestionsBuilder.size(limit);

SuggestResponse response =  
      elasticsearch.getClient()
        .prepareSuggest(elasticsearch.getIndexName())
        .addSuggestion(suggestionsBuilder)
        .execute().actionGet();
```

This working perfectly for suggestions with text, but not for blank suggestions.

In my attempts I have tried:

- Assigning an empty string ("") to searchTermLC, but that returns no
  options.
- Not supplying text to suggest on, but that throws a
  NullPointerException in the response.
- Using a search instead of suggest, but as weight is not one of the fields of the mapping I couldn't sort by it (Error: "No mapping found for [keyword_suggest.weight] in order to sort on"). The default sort was alphabetical on the output.

---

I want the top 10 results of all documents in the completion mapping, sorted by their score.

Comment: have you found a solution on this one? Currently looking for something like this

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have an empty string, no score can be computed for the completion suggester. It has indeed no sense to score in this situation.

Matching all documents and sorting based on the weight, you can obtain the ten highest documents according to the weight.

```
POST my_type/_search
{
    "sort":{"suggest_field_name.weight": {"order": "desc"}}
}
```

Since the results will likely always be the same when the input field is empty, you can cache the top results in you application.

Comment: With the empty string I'm not looking for a score, and I don't think the _suggest call uses score anyway, it matches via a tree structure. Search was my second attempt, but as I said I get "No mapping found for [keyword_suggest.weight] in order to sort on".